# Obtaining "greedy" pattern-matching in macros

Tags: macros, tex-core

Consider the following input to TeX:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013)
**\def\a#1\par{[#1]}

*\def\b#1\par{(#1)}

*\a\b five\par\par

*\end
```

Two definitions have the same delimiter, so there are in principle two ways for TeX to parse `\a\b five\par\par`:

1. "Non-greedy": First match `\b five` as the argument of `\a`, replacing `\b five\par` with [\b five]. Then match `five]` as the argument of `\b`, replacing `five]\par` with `(five])`.
2. "Greedy": First match `\b five\par` as the argument of `\a`, replacing `\b five\par\par` with `[\b five\par]`. Then match `five` as the argument of `\b`, replacing `five\par` with `(five)`.

The result of the above code is the "non-greedy" result:

[image]

My question is whether there is some way to redefine `\a` and `\b` so as to obtain the "greedy" result (without altering the fact that they have the same delimiter).

One commenter points out that I could use braces to group the arguments. Let's assume that it's also inconvenient for me to do that. E.g., I have a large document already with arbitrary text where `five` is in the example, and I don't want to go through and group everything.

Comment: Put braces around `\b five \par`.

Comment: @RyanReich good point. I've altered the question to avoid that easy solution.

Comment: Then, there's no way without introducing *some* modification.  You have to specify where the greedy search ends, and TeX will complain if it goes too far and doesn't find any more `\par`s.

Comment: No, and it doesn't make sense. How can TeX know how many `\par` tokens it has to jump over, given that it doesn't expand tokens when grabbing arguments? Nesting delimited argument macros is inherently wrong, using the same delimiter is shooting on one's own foot. I'm not saying this can't be solved for a particular controlled case; but would you ask the same question for regular expression matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it is not possible without changing *something*. I don't know if the following is practical in your case:

```
\long\def\a #1\par\a {[#1]}
\def\b #1\par{(#1)}
\a\b five\par\par\a

\bye
```

> [image: greedy]

The preceding way allows to pin-point *the* `\par` to be dealt with by `\a`. But, if you are always certain that `\a` will be followed by *two* `\par`'s, then there is

```
\def\a #1\par {\aa{#1\par}}
\long\def\aa #1\par {[#1]}

\def\b #1\par{(#1)}

\a\b five\par\par

\a\b five\par six\par

\bye
```

> [image: greedy2]

Or again, avoiding the creation of a group and getting crazy to avoid brace stripping on `#2` (braces around `#1` were already excluded from consideration as being evil).

```
\def\a #1\par {\aa{#1\par}\space}
\long\def\aa #1#2\par {[#1\romannumeral0#2]}

\def\b #1\par{(#1)}

\a\b five\par\par

\a\b five\par six\par

\a\b five\par {\let\x\empty}\par { \tt\meaning\x} 

\bye
```

> [image: greedy3]

Comment: This way, you have factually changed the delimiter of '\a' to '\par\a'.

Comment: @StephanLehmke indeed. Not knowing what the precise constraints of the OP are (is expandability required? is it only a matter of getting to the second `\par`? do we have to worry about brace removal?) we are a bit in the dark.

Comment: there is no `\gobble` in the Plain format, hence `\romannumeral0` to avoid defining another macro.

Comment: thanks for the ideas. as it turns out, there are exactly two `\par` to jump over in my application.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work for your example:

```
\def\a{\expandafter\@a}
\def\@a#1\par{[#1]}
```

It should be clear that a lot of things can go wrong trying to generalise this. But to judge that we'd need to know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Many things can go wrong, as you mention. For instance: `\a\bfseries\b five\par\par`

Comment: @tohecz Precisely. In fact as it stands, almost nothing but `\b` can come after `\a`.